# Is the Prouhet-Thue-Morse constant transcendental in any integer base $b>2$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, transcendental-numbers

The Prouhet-Thue-Morse constant, defined as

$$
\tau =\sum _{{i=0}}^{{\infty }}{\frac  {t_{i}}{2^{{i+1}}}}=0.412454033640\ldots 
$$

where the $t_i$ are elements of the Thue-Morse sequence, is transcendental. But is

$$
\tau_b =\sum _{{i=0}}^{{\infty }}{\frac  {t_{i}}{b^{{i+1}}}}
$$

also transcendental, for $b>2$?

Comment: I posted this question on Mathoverflow here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/326650/is-the-prouhet-thue-morse-constant-transcendental-in-any-integer-base-b2

Comment: @Travis Note that no one on my Mathoverflow question mentioned your very relevant comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is of course **yes**, see the MaothOverflow post [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/326650/is-the-prouhet-thue-morse-constant-transcendental-in-any-integer-base-b2).